# cisco flow vs ip flow

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, netflow

Using a 2900 series router and I encounter the following issue:

```
hostname#show flow monitor
  Flow Monitor TESTFLOW:
  Description:       User defined
  Flow Record:       TESTFLOW
  Flow Exporter:     TESTFLOW (inactive)
  Cache:
    Type:              normal
    Status:            allocated
    Size:              4096 entries / 10404496 bytes
    Inactive Timeout:  15 secs
    Active Timeout:    1800 secs
    Update Timeout:    1800 secs


hostname#show flow exporter
Flow Exporter TESTFLOW:
  Description:              User defined
  Export protocol:          NetFlow Version 9
  Transport Configuration:
    Destination IP address: 192.168.x.x
    Source IP address:      172.16.x.x
    Source Interface:       GigabitEthernet0/0
    Transport Protocol:     UDP
    Destination Port:       3008
    Source Port:            61496
    DSCP:                   0x0
    TTL:                    255
    Output Features:        Used
  Options Configuration:
    exporter-stats (timeout 100 seconds)
```

Why does the `Flow Exporter:     TESTFLOW (inactive)` appear?

How can I set it to active?

Comment: Have you referred to this [documentation](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/fnetflow/configuration/guide/12_2sr/fnf_12_2_sr_book/cfg_de_fnflow_exprts.html#wp1056627)?

Comment: @timmeyh can you please give us the command where you change the record size. I have the same problem. BR,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: netflow record size was too big.